# NumPad shortcut keys in AutoCAD 2018

Tags: autocad

I'm using an engineering software based on **Autodesk AutoCAD 2018 OEM** and I need to assign **keyboard shortcuts to NumPad keys** directly, without any modifier (SHIFT, CTRL, ALT).

On older version of Autocad this was possible, but now even though it's possible to assign NumPad keys directly, they do not work. According to [this page](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-lt/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/AutoCAD-LT/files/GUID-9970E91B-A4F5-405C-99C1-46AD804A8858-htm.html) on the AutoCAD LT knowledge base: *"Valid modifier and key combinations include Number Pad (NUMPADn) keys containing no modifiers"* and I hope the same is true for the "standard" AutoCAD (i.e. no "LT").

In fact I'm able to assign a shortcut to - for example - "Scale" function to NUMPAD(8), as in the screenshot below:

[image]

But then I'm not able to use it because if I press the NumPad 8 with **Num Lock ON** the AutoCAD console reads an 8:

[image]

... and if I keep the **Num Lock OFF** then the console picks the previous command (as it's the same that pushing the <kbd>↑</kbd>).

So if this feature is documented and the **cui** AutoCAD command allows me to choose that keys, how are they suppose to work? How can I assign a key to speed up my work without using a modifier?

Comment: Edit the keyboard map?

Comment: For the record, I've had some success asking such questions at the Autodesk forums (they can be really slow to answer, though).

Comment: @SolarMike Isn't what I tried with the `cui` command?

Comment: @Wasabi Thanks, I tried posting there too.

Comment: So let me follow what you are saying : you are using  package based on a version of software but reading the instructions from a third version and wondering why it does not work - have I got that correct?

Comment: @SolarMike Partially. It doesn't work on the AutoCAD 2018 OEM based software, but neither in the "full" AutoCAD 2018 (nor in the 2015, I've just tried that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the error: basically you cannot assign any NumPad key to AutoCAD 2015 or newer (2018 included) and in any flavour (Full, LT, OEM, etc.) when using a keyboard different from English (mine was Italian).

[image]

So, to **workaround** this bug, change/add an **English keyboard BEFORE starting your AutoCAD product** and then you'll be able to assign the correct Numpad key in the **Customize User Interface** dialog. It will appear as **NUMPAD8** and it will work even after deleting the English keyboard (if not used).

[image]